# Query to select columns having zero as well as null values

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT ename,comm 
FROM emp
WHERE ISNULL(comm,0)= 0;
```

Please explain this query .
This Query selects the emp records whose commission is null as well as zero.
[image]

Comment: `WHERE comm IS NULL OR comm = 0`

Comment: Yes , we can get the same result using OR. But without using OR we have to write a query .And this is the answer for this.
SELECT ename,comm FROM emp
WHERE ISNULL(comm,0)= 0; I did not get this where condition. Please explain that WHERE condition . Thanks

Comment: Sorry, in that case I do not know what question you are asking

Comment: Are you sure that should be `ISNULL` and not [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull)?

Comment: *`ISNULL(comm,0)`* usage will result in syntax error - this function have one argument only. Use COALESCE() function. From the other side this condition is not SARGable, use the condition provided by @RiggsFolly.

Comment: Yes. it is ISNULL only . Not a IFNULL

Answer (score 0):

`ISNULL` in MYSQL have only one parameter and it's true/false test if variable is null.

`IFNULL` in MYSQL has 2 params

`IFNULL(expr1, expr2)` - if expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1,  otherwise it returns expr2.

`IFNULL(expr1,0)` return 0 in two cases:

- expr1 = 0
- expr1 is NULL (in that case second param - 0 is returned)

[MYSQL IFNULL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull)

[MYSQL DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6064f170d264d14ce5825d4eacdc09d9)

In Transact-SQL there is `ISNULL` function with two params `ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )` and it works exactly like MYSQL `IFNULL`

[T-SQL ISNULL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

[SQL server DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6064f170d264d14ce5825d4eacdc09d9)